# The "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" package is not loading correctly for no reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to create a new winforms project, but Visual Studio prompts such a message

The "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" package is not loading correctly for no reason
This issue can be caused by a configuration change or by installing another extension.

For this reason, I specifically checked the installed nuget, and there is no nuget package related to Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools from the beginning to the end.

But in the follow-up work, I did not find any other abnormalities. In line with the work attitude of seeking truth and being pragmatic, does anyone know the reason for this pop-up prompt?

Comment: It’s an extension not a nuget package

Comment: Thanks very much for this important information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason Goemaat said, Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools is an extension rather than a nuget package, you need to see SQL Server Data Tools in Extensions=>Manage Extensions=>Installed.

[image]

[image]

If you want to fix this error follow the steps below:

Solution 1: Download the ISO image of SQL Server Data Tools in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn864412(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and install manually

Solution 2: Check whether SQL Server Data Tools needs to be updated in Extensions=>Manage Extensions=>Updates

Comment: That link is for Visual Studio 2013 but the post specifies Visual Studio 2022.